# flutter_typeahead not finding suggestions after removing all characters from TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-typeahead

I'm using [Flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) to display suggested country names and flags when the user types in the name of a country.
It all works great when typing in the name at the first time but after failing to get a suggestion once my `getSuggestion` method can't find any other suggestions even after removing a few characters.
This is a more detailed description on how this bug appears:

**1.** When clicking on the input field for the first time it successfully loads all the Country names and flags. As seen in the image below:

[image]

**2.** If I input characters that don't evaluate to a suggestion it displays my `noItemsFoundBuilder`

[image]

**3.** But if I now remove all the characters from the `TypeAheadField` my `getSuggestions` method can't find any suggestions

[image]

This is my `getSuggestions` method:

```
static List<CustomCountry> getSuggestions(String query) {
  countries.retainWhere(
      (country) => country.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
  return countries;
}
```

My `countries` variable is just a List of my CustomCountry class which looks like this:

```
static final List<CustomCountry> countries = [
    const CustomCountry(
        name: "Afghanistan", 
        flagUrl: "https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg"),
    const CustomCountry(
        name: "Åland Islands",
        flagUrl: "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg"), 
    ...
]
```

This is my `TypeAheadField`:

```
TypeAheadField(
  textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
      cursorWidth: 1,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        labelText: L.of(context).country,
        labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
        )),
      ),
      onChanged: (value) => context.read<CreateDidBloc>().add(
            CreateDidCountryChanged(country: value),
          )),
  suggestionsCallback: (value) {
    return CountryService.getSuggestions(value);
  },
  itemBuilder: (context, CustomCountry suggestion) {
    final country = suggestion;

    return ListTile(
      contentPadding:
          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
      leading: SizedBox(
        height: 30,
        width: 45,
        child: SvgPicture.network(country.flagUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Row(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(width: 7.5),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 7.5),
                  ],
                )),
      ),
      title: Text(
        country.name,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      ),
    );
  },
  noItemsFoundBuilder: (context) => Container(
    height: 50,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(L.of(context).noCountriesFound),
    ),
  ),
  onSuggestionSelected: (CustomCountry? suggestion) {
    final country = suggestion!;

    context.read<CreateDidBloc>().add(
          CreateDidCountryChanged(country: country.name),
        );
  },
);
```

I have already checked if the value/query maybe doesn't update anymore after getting no suggestion once but the query is the exact value inputted into the TextField even after getting no suggestion once. The returned value of suggestions is just an empty arrray after no fuggestion found and removing the character (displayed in step 3 above).
I hope I can get some information on why that bug appears or if my `getSuggestion` function just doesn't handle the removal of characters after no suggestion is found.

Comment: use `where` instead of `retainWhere` - something like `return countries.where(...).toList();`

Comment: When I use `where` it returns all the countries I have in my list. So it doesn't sort out the countries not containing the query

Comment: I got it to work now having a look into the [examples](https://github.com/AbdulRahmanAlHamali/flutter_typeahead/blob/master/example/lib/data.dart). I will answer my question to explain it

Comment: no, it will not return all the items, simply do: `return countries.where(...).toList();` - now you probably are doing: `countries.where(...); return countries;`

Comment: Yea you are right! I must have done some error when I tried countries.where before. It's working now. Thanks

Comment: sure, your welcome